# Функции плагина BarcodeScanner в PhoneGap-приложении для сканирования QR-кода ничего не возвращает - почему?

Tags: javascript, ios, плагин, phonegap, cordova

Имеется PhoneGap мобильное приложение в котором предполагается использовать сканер QR-кода. Использую плагин: [BarcodeScanner](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/951), делаю всё по инструкции:

Добавил в config.xml:

```
<plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" spec="2.0.0" source="pgb" />
```

Ну и собственно js-код сканирования:

```
 cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
   );
```

В итоге, при вызове этого кода, действительно открывается окно камеры, QR-код сканируется, ну а дальше ничего не происходит, т.е после сканирования никаких alert'ов.

Тесты провожу на iPhone5, в его системном логе по поводу моего приложения написано следующее:

```
Oct 11 20:18:49 iPhone MyApp[4669] <Warning>: WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x15de5610> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
Oct 11 20:18:49 iPhone MyApp[4669] <Warning>: WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x15de5610> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
Oct 11 20:18:49 iPhone MyApp[4669] <Warning>: WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x15de5610> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
Oct 11 20:18:58 iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleH4CamIn::ISP_FlushInactiveDARTMappings: 0x00000000
Oct 11 20:18:58 iPhone MyApp[4669] <Error>: -[CDVPluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d28ad0
```

Что не так? Куда копать?

Comment: ну как вы видите, у вас нет функции `toSuccessCallbackString`. либо это метод делегата, и вам его надо написать, либо если это метод библиотеки, видимо какая то ее часть не подключена

Comment: напишите issue на гитхабе, там вам быстрее ответят

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился использованием более свежей версии плагина 2.2.0:

```
<plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" spec="2.2.0" source="pgb" />
```

а также подключением js-файла плагина в index.html файле:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
```